# How to move a marker in an OpenLayers.Layer.Markers layer?

Tags: openlayers

How can I programmatically move an existing marker on an `OpenLayers.Layer.Markers` layer? I can't seem to find a proper way.

Is this supported at all? Or do I have to use the `Vector` layer?

The `marker.moveTo()` function doesn't work for me, I have the coordinate in lat/lon.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`marker.moveTo()` is not "official" APIMethod. It's used internally by other methods in OpenLayers and you are actually discouraged to use methods that are not marked as "APIMethod".

Wouldn't removing and adding marker on new position fulfill your requirement? There are `removeMarker()` and `addMarker()` APIMethods for that.

If not, I would consider using Vector layer as it's much more flexible in terms om rendering and manipulation features.

Comment: Probably removing and adding the marker would work, though I don't know how the performance would be with many markers in a layer. That's why I'd like to have seen a move() method. However, I have decided to go for `Vector` now. Thanks.

Answer (score 11):

if you have lon/lat for the new point then marker could be moved as:

```
var newLonLat = new OpenLayers.LonLat(lon, lat);
var newPx = map.getLayerPxFromLonLat(newLonLat);
myMarker.moveTo(newPx);
```

Answer (score 1):

This is **not** a fully working example demonstrating moving marker on click event

coffeescript:

```
projection_4326 = new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:4326") #Transform from WGS 1984
projection_900913 = new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:900913") # Spherical Mercator Projection
markers = new OpenLayers.Layer.Markers( "Markers")
marker = new OpenLayers.Marker(new OpenLayers.LonLat(0,0).transform(projection_4326, projection_900913), icon)
markers.addMarker(marker)
map = new OpenLayers.Map(...init...stuff)
map.addLayers([markers])
map.events.register "click", map, (e) ->
            opx = map.getLayerPxFromViewPortPx(e.xy)
            lonLat = map.getLonLatFromPixel(e.xy)
            # now, if your coordinates are in EPSG:4326 you would have to convert the lonLat here
            #new_position = marker.lonlat.transform(projection_4326, projection_900913)
            marker.map = map
            marker.moveTo(opx) #or new_position
```