# How to get marker which is already added in markers layer

Tags: openlayers, marker

Basically i want to change the marker position dynamically by changing its longitude and latitude.

how do i do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
myMarker.moveTo(map.getPixelFromLonLat(new OpenLayers.LonLat(-98, 35)));
```

Here's a [DEMO/Example LINK](http://jsfiddle.net/PUkQ7/2/)

Just click on the move marker button.
[image]

Comment: Could work, but [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9291473/2835520) **that are not marked as "APIMethod"**, and recommend to remove the marker and add new one with new coordinates.