# If I have this mapbox API call in a function, why does this evented callback only occasionally get called?

Tags: javascript, mapbox

I have the following setup using the mapbox API.  When using geolocate.watchPosition on my laptop and walking around to simulate real time tracking of a user's position on a map, the map marker only updates very occasionally.  What am I doing wrong?  Is there something wrong with the callback timing?  I'm assuming map.on('locationfound'...) will be called when the map.locate() function completes successfully.

```
  L.mapbox.accessToken = 'xxxx';
  var map = L.mapbox.map('map', 'mapbox.high-contrast');

  var myLayer = L.mapbox.featureLayer().addTo(map);



 map.on('locationfound', function(e) {
      map.fitBounds(e.bounds);
      console.log('location found callback');
      myLayer.setGeoJSON({
          type: 'Feature',
          geometry: {
              type: 'Point',
              coordinates: [e.latlng.lng, e.latlng.lat]
          },
          properties: {
              'title': 'Here I am!',
              'marker-color': '#ff8888',
              'marker-symbol': 'star'
          }
      });

function myFunc(position) {
  map.locate(); //part of mapbox API
}

watchId = navGeolocate.watchPosition(myFunc, {}, {});
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/22959535/438992 I mean, it will be, but I don't think you're in control of that. You can set a timeout, you can set the accuracy.

Comment: @Dave Newton, does this mean it's possible to do "real time location tracking" (at least within a few hundred millisec) of a user as they walk around with their browser open that is calling watchPosition()??